# How to trigger keydown, return key

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I have bind the keydown, return, event like this:

```
$('#inout').bind('keydown', 'return', function (evt){
      someFunction();
});
```

How to trigger this when I want in other places?

This trigger do the error:

```
$(this).trigger( $.Event( 'keydown', { keyCode: 13, which: 13 } ));
```

**I can't change bind method**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to trigger a keydown event with jQuery:

```
var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
event.which = 13; // A random key (Enter)
$('#inout').trigger(event);
```

You can check an example in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej9o1wwg/).

Comment: it does not work if event bind like I described, this trigger got an error

Comment: I added a fiddle with the exact same code you're using to bind to the event so it may be related to something else.